# I have an object with participants and participantsIdentities array properties. Both properties have participantId property. How to link them?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm currently looping through some participants and displaying stats for each participant using Vue.js v-for. However, I also want to display the summonerName of that participant along with his stats.

The problem is that the information about the user is contained in participantIdentities but his stats are contained in participants. I assume I can somehow link the two properties using the participantId property which is present in both cases, however, I am unsure how to do so.

```
<div class='participant' v-for='participant in match.details.participants'>
    <p>{{ participant.stats.kills }}/</p>
    <p>{{ participant.stats.deaths }}/</p>
    <p>{{ participant.stats.assists }}</p>
</div>
```

How the related properties of the object look:

```
details: Object
    participantIdentities: Array(10)
        0:
            participantId: 1
            player: Object
                summonerName: "Test"
                summonerIcon: 1337
    participants: Array(10)
        0:
            participantId: 1
            stats: Object
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to basically perform a join on two arrays of objects based on a property. I like to create Maps from my arrays, then use [object spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) to join them together. It is done like so:

```js
var a = [{id: 1, name: 'johnny'}, {id: 2, name: 'joey'}];
var b = [{id: 1, type: 24152}, {id: 2, type: 325723}];

// convert the arrays to key/value pair where the key is the id and the value is the object itself 
var mapA = new Map(a.map(x => [x.id, x]));
var mapB = new Map(b.map(x => [x.id, x]));

const merged = [];
for (var [key, val] of mapA) { // iterate through the values of mapA
 merged.push({...val, ...mapB.get(key)}); // Join the object from mapA with the object from mapB using the spread operator 
}

console.log(merged)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the arrays by id

```
participants.sort(function(a, b){return a.id - b.id});
participantIdentities.sort(function(a, b){return a.id - b.id});
```

Then you can just add the index to the v-for and get the array element

```
<div class='participant' v-for='(participant, index) in 
match.details.participants'>
    <p>{{ participant.stats.kills }}/</p>
    <p>{{ participant.stats.deaths }}/</p>
    <p>{{ participantIdentities[index].player.summonerName }}</p>
</div>
```